# listView Search in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I create listView by use the following code.If i use lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
i get the list View filter.If i set the filter text its not display the filtered listView.How to set the filter text;

```
 lv=new ListView(this);        
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, items)); 
    //lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setFilterText("a");
```

Note :

I have the TextViews A to Z . When i touch letter 'a' i wish to list the elements starts with 'a' so that i need to set the list filter at run time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, items);        
lv.setListAdapter(adapter);        
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
adapter.getFilter().filter("a");
```

Comment: Thank you It's working.Before filter when i click the list item i take the item position.After take the item position i get the value from the array[itemposition].After listView filter how do take the clicked item .

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521775/onitemclick-gives-index-position-of-item-on-visible-page-not-actual-index-of