# Android listview get right position of list item when textfilter

Tags: android, listview, position

I have a question about the listview. I have a listview with textfilter enabled. When I click a listitem without textfilter I get the position and I give it to the next activity which show the right text based on the position. But when I use the text filter and click an item it the next activity shows me the wrong text, probably because the positions of the listitems changed. Does somebody have a solution for this problem, e.g not working with positions but another reference from a list item? I looked everywhere but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's easier for us if you put more code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the correct item at `position` from the listAdapter directly. It contains only the current items displayed in the list.

```
listAdapter .getItem(position);
```

Reference : [onItemClick gives index/ position of item on visible page ... not actual index of the item in list ..problem on enabling setTextFilterEnabled .. android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521775/onitemclick-gives-index-position-of-item-on-visible-page-not-actual-index-o?rq=1)

Comment: But that's the problem. I don't want only the current displayed items I want all the items!

Comment: you can fetch the item from listadapter and send the only required data to the other activity through intent extras..

Comment: But will it be the right position (the position in the unfiltered list) or in the shown, filtered list?

Comment: get item in first activity itself.. put all data from the item to intent and start activity... in the next activity get all data from intent and use..

Comment: no need to send position.. as you cannot get the correct item's posiiton in the orginal list...

Answer (score 0):

If there is something wrong with `position`, you can change from `id` to `position`. When list is filtered the `position` in [`onClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) event is the new position in filtered list not the old one. Normal, `id` is the order of your item in input data

Comment: id does exactly the same as position