# OnClickListener applies to the last element in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Library being used [SwipCards](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/lorentzos/flingswipe/SwipeFlingAdapterView.java)

I have an ArrayList that loop through a number of cards are move like a deck of cards (similar to Tinder's UI) I decided to add an onclicklistener so that the style applied to the card would be changed on click and it works but it only works on the last card in the ArrayList.

```
flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new 
SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
  @override
  public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {
    if (findViewById(R.id.namecard).getVisibility() == (View.VISIBLE)){
     findViewById(R.id.namecard).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else if (findViewById(R.id.namecard).getVisibility() == (View.GONE)){
     findViewById(R.id.namecard).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else if (findViewById(R.id.namecard).getVisibility() == (View.VISIBLE)){
     findViewById(R.id.namecard).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
  }

})
```

Is there a way to get the styling effect to apply to the top card in the stack (the card in view) instead of the bottom card in the Arraylist (the last card)?

I've tried [this solution,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521775/onitemclick-gives-index-position-of-item-on-visible-page-not-actual-index-o) but it doesn't seem to work even if I've replaced certain aspects to match the library I'm using

Comment: I suggest you assign `namecard` to a local variable, or even a field. You're potentially looking it up 4 times per click (which isn't free).

Comment: @AjahnCharles Please forgive my ignorance with Java, can I create the equivalent of a php session in Java for the current user's information....?

Comment: Within the lifecycle of an activity, you can just store information as fields within the activity class (or better yet, you can use a ViewModel https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel). Between Activities, you can pass small amounts of data using Intent extras (I usually only pass ids, or field values for multi-step forms). Beyond that you can use SharedPreferences or a local db like Android​ Room or Realm.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using this Library and you want to manipulate the card in view the solution is to getSelectedView()

```
flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new  SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
@override
 public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {

    View view = flingContainer.getSelcetedView();
    if (view.findViewById(R.id.namecard).getVisibility() == (View.VISIBLE)){
     view.findViewById(R.id.namecard).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else if (view.findViewById(R.id.namecard).getVisibility() == (View.GONE)){
      view.findViewById(R.id.namecard).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else if (view.findViewById(R.id.namecard).getVisibility() == (View.VISIBLE)){
     view.findViewById(R.id.namecard).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    })
```